# Using multiple popup windows with bPopup

Tags: javascript

I'm using a lightweight jQuery popup plugin called 'bPopup'. I'm using it on my website at the moment to load multiple popup windows when clicked. I was recently told that my code was inefficient as I was loading multiple popups with multiple JavaScript 'listeners':

```
<script type="text/javascript">
;(function($) {
$(function() {
    $('#my-button_1').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#element_to_pop_up_32754925023').bPopup();
    });
});
})(jQuery);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
;(function($) {
$(function() {
    $('#my-button_2').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#element_to_pop_up_95031153149').bPopup();
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

^^ The multiple JavaScript 'listeners'. And, for the Popups:

```
<!-- Button that triggers the popup -->
<a class="main" id="my-button_1" href="#">Popup 1</a></b><br />
<!-- Element to pop up -->
<div id="element_to_pop_up_1">
// ...
</div>


<!-- Button that triggers the popup -->
<a class="main" id="my-button_1" href="#">Popup 1</a></b><br />
<!-- Element to pop up -->
<div id="element_to_pop_up_1">
// ...
</div>
```

He's probably right (sure of it), but not sure how to implement this, or whether this is even possible (small chance he's wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is right.  Think about maintenance.

If you wanted to add another link that popped up another element you would need to add yet another listener function.  Removing one would be the same thing.  Too many things to keep track of.

Change the code to add the event according to a class name and then you can bind to all at once.  Then include the popup element ID within the attributes of the opener link.

```
$('.popup-opener').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $($(this).attr('popup-element')).bPopup();
});

<!-- Button that triggers the popup -->
<a class="main popup-opener" popup-element="element_to_pop_up_1" id="my-button_1" href="#">Popup 1</a></b><br />
<!-- Element to pop up -->
<div id="element_to_pop_up_1">
// ...
</div>
```

Better yet, use the `on()` function to bind the event.  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Adding new openers now requires no changes to the javascript.

Comment: Yeah, figured it out yesterday (I'm a complete amateur with JS), thanks anyway!! :)

Comment: I think its working with @nickles80 code. The popup button just needs to be like this (Note the `#` is added): `popup-element="#element_to_pop_up_1"`

Answer (score 0):

The below function ( myFunction() ) takes the Id of anchor/div tag which is clicked and another id of div content to be display. And applies the same style for all popup models. And also it hides the old popup which already opened when u open new popup. All popup properties you can change.

Here i used only for two popups but you can use it for many as same did here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction(whId,whtDivContent,e) {
    //var totWidth = $(document).width();
    //var marTop = position.top;
    var elt = $(whId);
    var position = elt.position();
    var marLeft = position.left - 130;

    if(marLeft <= 1) {
        marLeft = 10;
    }

    var openModal_profile ='#openModal_profile';
    var openModal_menu ='#openModal_menu';

    // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
    e.preventDefault();

    $(whtDivContent).bPopup({
        position: [marLeft, 0] //x, y
        ,opacity: 0.9
        ,closeClass : 'b-close'
        ,zIndex: 2
        ,positionStyle: 'fixed' //'fixed' or 'absolute' 'relative'
        ,follow: [false,false] //x, y
        ,onOpen: function() {
            if(openModal_profile == whtDivContent) {
                $(openModal_menu).bPopup().close();
            }
            else if(openModal_menu == whtDivContent) {
                $(openModal_profile).bPopup().close();
            }

            $(whId).css({'background-color':"#DFDFDF"}); 
        }
        ,onClose: function() { $('.close').click(); $(whId).css({'background-color':""}); }

    });
}


;(function($) {
    // DOM Ready
    $(function() {
       // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
       //$(id_menu).on('click',function(e) {}

       var id_menu = '#id_menu';
       var openModal_menu ='#openModal_menu';
       $(id_menu).toggle(function(e) {
           //$(id_menu).css({'background-color':"#DFDFDF"});
           myFunction(id_menu,openModal_menu,e);
       },function(e){
           //$(id_menu).css({'background-color':""});
           $('.close').click();
           $(openModal_menu).bPopup().close();

       });

       var id_profile = '#id_profile';
       var openModal_profile ='#openModal_profile';
       $(id_profile).toggle(function(e) {
           //$(id_profile).css({'background-color':"#DFDFDF"});
           myFunction(id_profile,openModal_profile,e);
       },function(e){
           //$(id_profile).css({'background-color':""});

           $(openModal_profile).bPopup().close();
       });

    //ENDS HERE    
    });
})(jQuery);    


</script>
```